# How to create wildcards in Firebase Dynamic Links?

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

How can I configure a dynamic link to trigger on all subdomains on my website, and pass the url as data?

I want to be able to take any url from the browser and paste it in an email.
If clicked I want it to open in the app instead of the browser if the app is installed.

LinkedIn, Facebook and others do this but I cant figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not something you do with Firebase Dynamic Links then.
What you are looking for is deep-linking. Imagine your `apple-app-site-association` manifest.

```
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
    {
      "appID": "{your.App.ID.here}",
      "paths": ["/path/to/url/", "/another/path/to/url"]
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

Although I am not certain if this is what firebase does (as one cannot specify such a thing in android's manifest, but in the app itself only), this is one way how to think about it.
If instead of using firebase dynamic links you would manually add android and osx manifests to your project without specifying any path, it would work for your entire website.

There are many articles about setting up deep-links and, to be more specific, deferred ones, but, to pick one, you can start with [adjust.com's guide to deep linking](https://www.adjust.com/blog/dive-into-deeplinking/)